# Prevent USMT 5 from migrating deleted AD profiles

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory, user-profiles, usmt

I'm working on a project to replace desktops and laptops. 
Some shared desktops have dozens of profiles, some of which are users that have left the organisation and should not be migrated to the new hardware.

How do I get USMT to ignore these? Or should this be default behavior and am I including them via one of the xml-files that Scanstate uses? 
Is there anything I could insert in a custom xml to force the ignoring of non-existed profiles?

My current Scanstate command:

```
scanstate.exe B:\USMT\%computername% /o /c /uel:365 /ue:*\Administrator* /targetWindows7 /vsc /listfiles:B:\USMT\%computername%\gatheredfiles.log /l:B:\USMT\%computername%\scanstate.log /v:5 /i:miguser.xml /i:migsys.xml /i:profiles.xml /config:config.xml
```

Comment: Its very broad to provide answer, this link might help you with some extent https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/05/05/usmt-and-u-migrating-only-fresh-domain-profiles/